# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contact_name' of null

Tags: javascript

В зависимости от того, что вернет определенный метод в res, там может быть contact_name или нет. Если нет, приходит ошибка "Cannot read property 'contact_name' of null". Как этого можно избежать?

```
if (typeof res.contact_name !=  'undefined') {
  ...
```

Comment: _"Cannot read property 'contact_name' of null"_ - намекает, что идет попытка обращения к свойству объекта, который равен _null_. Следовательно проверять надо не `res.contact_name`, а сам `res`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если `contact_name` null, то банально так:

```
if (res.contact_name) {
...
...
```

Если `res` null, то банально так:

```
if (res) {
...
...
```

```js
var res = {};
res.contact_name = null;

if (res.contact_name) 
  console.log('я существую'); 
else 
  console.log('меня нет');
```

---

```js
var res = null;
    
if (res) 
  console.log('я существую'); 
else 
  console.log('меня нет');
```

Comment: похоже ты не дочитал вопрос :-) у него ошибка в том, что сам `res` -> `null`

Comment: @Grundy `там может быть contact_name или нет. Если нет, приходит ошибка "Cannot read property 'contact_name' of null".`  не?

Comment: *"Cannot read property 'contact_name' of null"* - как бы говорит нам, что все падает, когда ты пытаешься обратиться к этому свойству, то есть твой код **if (res.contact_name)** точно так же упадет как и код в вопросе :-)

Comment: @Grundy ну добавил в ответ, чоЖ

Comment: Ну хотя бы так :-)

Comment: Да, дополнительная проверка на равенство res null пришлась весьма кстати, спасибо :)

Comment: Наверное надо бы сделать [tag:faq]: _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of null or undefined_

Comment: @Grundy вполне. можешь заняться